# Where to store deviceId and token of user device in Meteor.js (push notifications)

Tags: android, ios, meteor, push-notification

I want to ask where to store the user token and device id and os for a push notification when I am using meteor.js?

Comment: You can extend the user document because each user has a representative document in Meteor.users but you need a method and a publication to make it secure.

Comment: Is this a best practices? Should I put it in the profile, or is it better to be directly in the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in Meteor docs, best practice is to extend the Meteor.users collection.

https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data

It is not adviced to store them in profile (https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile) but rather directly to "add a new uniquely-named top-level field on the user document".

If new need a hook on the user creation when creating their account or when loggingin you can use onCreateUser (https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser) or or onLogin https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin.

Be then careful how you publish your new data to the user, especeilly if those are private information.